# How to execute program before the uninstallation starts?

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

Can InnoSetup execute a program before the uninstallation starts? My program creates some registry values. I have an executable that can remove those registry values and my question is, can InnoSetup run that executable before the uninstallation starts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) on `Setup Script Sections`, particularly the `UninstallRun` one at the bottom of the tree:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\INIT.EXE"; Parameters: "/x"
```

If you need to do something more complex, you can also do it in code using the Pascal scripting functionality in InnoSetup. See `UninstallCodeExample1.iss' in the`InnoSetup 5\Examples` folder.

Comment: The first line works: Filename: "{app}\INIT.EXE"; Parameters: "/x"

Comment: The second two lines aren't even valid in an `[UninstallRun]` section.  But never mind as they're irrelevant to the solution anyway.

Comment: @Miral: They were copied from the Inno Setup documentation directly (from the link I provided). I should have read more carefully. I'll make the correction - thanks for the information. :-)