# Kill process before (re)install using "taskkill /f /im" in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, taskkill

I install a service/daemon, which needs to be killed before uninstall and reinstall.

I already found out [how to do it for uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023790/how-to-execute-program-before-the-uninstallation-starts):

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "taskkill"; Parameters: "/im ""My Service.exe"" /f"; Flags: runhidden
```

The `[Run]` section, however, runs after install, so I can't use it for that. What is the best way to kill the process using `taskkill` before install?

Please note that I specifically want to kill the process. [A more complex solution using IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507853/close-running-version-of-program-before-installing-update-inno-setup) offers no benefits in my case, I just want to execute `taskkill` before installing a particular file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found a way using the `BeforeInstall` parameter and a simple Pascal Script function in the code section. I added a string parameter so it can be reused for multiple processes.

```
[Files]
Source: "My Service 1.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    BeforeInstall: TaskKill('My Service 1.exe')
Source: "My Service 2.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    BeforeInstall: TaskKill('My Service 2.exe')
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure TaskKill(FileName: String);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec('taskkill.exe', '/f /im ' + '"' + FileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

Comment: In case taskkill.exe isn't found by environment PATH, you could set an absolute path to it: `Exec(ExpandConstant('{sys}\taskkill.exe'), '/f /im ' + '"' + FileName + '"', ExpandConstant('{sys}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);`

Comment: not always work, taskkill in one of my client sometime response 'Out of memory' error

Answer (score 14):

Unless the installer needs to run on a Windows XP machine, or you have set [`CloseApplications` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplications) to `no` (the default is `yes`), the installer should close the application automatically:

[image]

*The functionality is available since [Inno Setup 5.5](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.0) on Windows Vista and newer.*

---

Though sometimes `yes` is not enough, you need to use `force`:
[Installer created via Inno Setup, can't close applications during installation on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38590311/850848)