# Inno Setup Postpone locked file replacing to the next restart during silent installation

Tags: windows, delphi, inno-setup, pascal

In Inno Setup installer (5.5.1(a)) during upgrade `.exe` is being replaced. When the exe is locked, it is showing error

> DeleteFile failed; code 5.
>   Access is denied.
>   Abort, Retry, Ignore

How to suppress message during silent upgrade please help me. By default during silent installation it should take *Ignore* option without any error.

[image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it makes sense to ignore/skip the file. I assume you need to replace it during upgrade, don't you?

---

You can have a different entry for silent and non-silent installations:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\path\MyProg.exe; Dest: {app}; Check: not WizardSilent
Source: C:\path\MyProg.exe; Dest: {app}; Flags: restartreplace; Check: WizardSilent
```

Comment: Ty, Yes i need to replace it during upgrade, So according to you best way is in [Files] section for particular .exe use restartreplace flag and Check WizardSilent will not show any error during Silent Upgrade

Comment: It does prevent the setup from running, if the mutex exists (= if a application that creates the mutex is still running)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it won't be able to replace your executable because that file is still running. Why don't you just kill that process through BeforeInstall ?.

[Kill process before (re)install using "taskkill /f /im" in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776405/kill-process-before-reinstall-using-taskkill-f-im-in-inno-setup)

This approach won't help if your problem is because you have no rights to modify that file though.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any other way so that i can SUPPRESSMSGBOX.   ex-Changing flag to restartreplace in [Files] section will it help during silent installation

Comment: The attached image above is the error from windows or innosetup and we are doing silent installation by User not by administrator.

Comment: You can not install as user in program files

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know how to suppress that messagebox